# Horizontal split terminal Mac El Captain

Tags: macos, osx-el-capitan

There is a post about [vertical split in OSX](http://old.evanmeagher.net/2010/12/patching-screen-with-vertical-split-in-os) but this post is fairly old. I am not sure if this still works with El Captain which has System Integrity Protection enabled . I am afraid modifying some system files is not allowed from now on i.e. terminal. However, even if its allowed, I want to split terminal horizontally and not vertically. How would I do that?

```
$ cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@cvs.savannah.gnu.org:/sources/screen co screen
$ curl http://old.evanmeagher.net/files/gnu-screen-vertsplit.patch > gnu-screen-vertsplit.patch
$ cd screen/src
$ patch < ../../gnu-screen-vertsplit.patch
$ ./configure --enable-locale --enable-telnet --enable-colors256 --enable-rxct_osc
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

I typed the first command in terminal and it returned me:

```
-bash: cvs: command not found
```

NOTE: I have disabled SIP i.e. System Integrity Protection still I could do it because I was afraid to get few things broken. Also, there are no revert back steps on this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source-code for `screen` moved to Git.  Its [page on Savannah](http://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=screen) tells how to retrieve the sources.  There also have been development changes.

To do this, you will need `git`.  OSX has not bundled that.  To get it, I would start by installing [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) (some prefer [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) or [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/)), and install the git package using the `port` command, e.g.,

```
sudo port install git
```

(which puts it in `/opt/local/bin/git`).  The [`git clone`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html) command does a checkout, e.g,.

```
/private/tmp/foo (4) git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/screen.git
Cloning into 'screen'...
remote: Counting objects: 7706, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1549/1549), done.
remote: Total 7706 (delta 6164), reused 7670 (delta 6138)
Receiving objects: 100% (7706/7706), 3.44 MiB | 4.30 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (6164/6164), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
/private/tmp/foo (5) ls -l
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  7 tom  wheel    238 Oct 24 18:36 screen
-rw-r--r--  1 tom  wheel  12331 Oct 24 18:36 typescript
/private/tmp/foo (6) ls -l screen
total 80
-rw-r--r--    1 tom  wheel  35147 Oct 24 18:36 COPYING
drwxr-xr-x    3 tom  wheel    102 Oct 24 18:36 incoming
-rwxr-xr-x    1 tom  wheel   1150 Oct 24 18:36 mktar.pl
drwxr-xr-x  103 tom  wheel   3502 Oct 24 18:36 src
```

Once you have that, the remainder is following the (old) instructions and dealing with whatever nuisances have cropped up.

When investigating a possibly out-of-date patch, I would use the `--dry-run` option of patch, to see what rejects might exist, before messing up a source-tree.  That was added to GNU patch 2.5.4 in 1997.  OSX El Capitan has GNU patch 2.5.8 ("only" about ten years old), and its `--help` message lists the option.  Using that allows you to see if a patch applies cleanly without actually modifying the files.  Sometimes adding a  `-l` option (ignoring whitespace) helps.  More often, I apply the patch and work through the rejects.  There is some relevant discussion in [How to patch --dry-run but still view rejects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432126/how-to-patch-dry-run-but-still-view-rejects)

By the way, this option is misspelled: `--enable-rxct_osc`.  That should be "rx**v**t".

You will likely have additional questions—this should be enough to put you in the right direction.

Comment: what is --dry-run option of patch? I haven't heard of it.

Comment: also i can't figure out. How to install it from Git. Can you post steps in your answer?

Comment: I have git installed. I use homebrew